# Update: plotting % differences in Jupyter

Tags: python, plot, jupyter

I have two data sets and each one is forty three rows with four columns. I am trying to take the percentage difference from each corresponding row in the fourth column for each data set.
Here is an example of what some of my data sets look like. Once I have each percentage difference per year, I am hoping to plot the difference with year on x and % diff on y.

```
1980-01-01       0        0     8
1981-01-01       0        0    10
1982-01-01       0        0     2
1983-01-01       0        0     4
1984-01-01       0        0    11
```

and

```
1980-01-01       0        0     2
1981-01-01       0        0     3
1982-01-01       0        0     0
1983-01-01       0        0     2
1984-01-01       0        0     1
```

I have been working on this for awhile- someone helped me with a code to actually do the % differences, which is as follows. 'MELT' is the fourth column.

```
diffs = []
for x, y in zip(MELT_data_h5['MELT'], MELT_data_CP['MELT']):
    sum = ( y + x ) / 2
    sum = ( y - x ) / sum
    
    diffs.append(sum)
    
print(diffs)
```

Once I print this, I get a long list of numbers, here are a few values for visualization.

```
-1.2, -1.0769230769230769, -2.0, -0.6666666666666666, -1.6666666666666667, -0.8571428571428571, -2.0, -1.3103448275862069, -0.8108108108108109, -1.0303030303030303, -0.9433962264150944
```

These numbers can't be right because the percent differences can't be negative- what am I doing wrong? I know how to put the axes on the plot, I just can't quite figure out how to get accurate percent differences and then plot those against time.
Thank you so much if you read this, I'm new to Jupyter

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start. `print(MELT_data_h5['MELT'], MELT_data_CP['MELT'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you could be using the wrong formula?

Instead of the sum being calculated with

```
sum = ( y + x ) / 2
sum = ( y - x ) / sum
```

Is it possible to use

```
sum = ((y - x) / x) * 100
```

End result should be something like this:

```
    diffs = []
for x, y in zip(MELT_data_h5['MELT'], MELT_data_CP['MELT']):
    sum = ((y - x) / x) * 100
    diffs.append(sum)

print(diffs)
```

Comment: I tried that, here's what I got: '-75.0, -70.0, -100.0, -50.0, -90.9090909090909, -60.0, -100.0, -79.16666666666666' so still negative numbers. I have the right amount of numbers (43) but they're all negative which just isn't making sense

Comment: Is it possible that you have the wrong columns set up?